# «Околоопасные» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, прилагательные

«Околоопасные условия». Слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Ваше слово - окказионализм, несуществующее, но всё по правилам р. яз, как описано у Сержа.

Comment: да, я его не встречала...но существует ведь околоземный, например...рядом две гласных, это меня насторожило...

Comment: Именно по этому принципу - по формообразованию похожих слов - и образуются окказионализмы. Некоторые приживаются в языке... Но *условия около опасности* мой слух не приемлет.

Comment: Да, "около" только с существительными сочетается, около которых что-то физически находится - "около опасности" даже флажки не развесить - опасность абстрактна. Можно "условия, _близкие к опасным_" (формально "приравненные к опасным"), у. повышенной опасности. Как окказионализм - и то лучше "квазиопасные".

Comment: квази - это ложный, только кажущийся. Не то имелось в виду. Может написать "почти-опасные" или "предопасные" как окказионализм?

Comment: "Околоопасные условия" - плохо согласуется с логикой

Comment: Да, это затрудняет заинтересованным людям понимание того, опасно или не опасно на самом деле. "Повышенной опасности" - термин, который в отдельных применениях даже как формальный используется (с приписанием опасного диапазона величин и т. п.). Но и без уточнений интуитивно понятен.

Comment: это сказал специалист МЧС...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно слитное написание.

ОКОЛО... **Первая часть сложных слов. 1. Вносит зн.: находящийся на близком расстоянии вокруг, поблизости чего-л. Окололунный, околоорбитальный, околосолнечный, околоэкваторный.** 2. Вносит зн.: близкий к профессиональным кругам науки, культуры, спорта, политики, но не являющийся истинно профессиональным, творческим. Околопарламентский, околоспортивный. 3. Вносит зн.: относящийся к тому, связанный с тем, что указано во второй части слова. Околофутбольный. 4. Вносит зн.: близкий чему-л. по свойству. Околозвуковой (близкий по скорости звука).

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.